# Is 'of' needed in 'his playing (of) cards'?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds, participles, present-participles

"I saw him playing cards."

When this line is transformed, which of two following is correct and why?

"I saw his playing cards".

"I saw his playing **of** cards."

Comment: Compare with noun phrases that have *the* in them, for example: "*I saw him reading **the** will.*" versus "*I saw his reading of **the** will*".

Comment: @ToddWilcox why should I compare with noun phrase having 'the'?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best answer to your question is, but when *the* is present, it's a similar situation and it always would have **of** added. Also note that *playing* in your example sentence could either mean what he was doing or what kinds of cards he had. Like, *I saw his playing (with cards)* or *I saw his cards (the kind of cards used for playing games)*.

Comment: The first, while grammatically correct is semantically wrong, it suggests that you are looking at the cards that he is holding ie "I stood behind him and I saw his playing cards". The second could be correct but it's an unusual, possibly anachronistic usage.

Comment: To me "I saw his playing of cards" sounds either unnatural or very, very old-fashioned.  Far better "I saw his card playing" with card as an adjective conditioning the gerund or maybe "I saw his card-playing" with 'card-playing' as a compound noun.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence

> "I saw him playing cards."

Means he was playing cards with someone(Or solitaire).

The second sentence

> "I saw his playing of cards".

Means he saw a 'trick' or 'show' of cards played by him.

Comment: Not necessarily a trick, it could also simply refer to his standard approach to playing cards.